# Yii2 - How to add onchange event in activeform

Tags: javascript, yii2

This is my code :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'int_roomCatId')
          ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(TblCategory::find()->all(), 'int_category_id', 'str_category'), array('class' =>'form-control','prompt'=>'Select Room Category'))
          ->label('Room Category');  ?>
```

I want to add onchange = "getData()" event. where to add this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `htmloptions` array just do like below:

```
dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(TblCategory::find()->all(), 'int_category_id', 'str_category'), array('onchange'=>'getData()','class' =>'form-control','prompt'=>'Select Room Category'))
```

Each key and value in `htmloptions` array will be converted to html attributes, for example:

```
'key'=>'value'
```

Will be shown as :

```
<tag key="value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call using below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'product_name')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Products::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), 
             ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Product-',
              'onchange'=>'
                $.get( "index.php?r=suborders/listprice&id="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                  $( "#suborders-product_price" ).val( data );
                });
            ']);
    ?>
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
    echo $form->field($flightSearchForm, "lastDepartTimeChange", 
        ['options' => ['class' => 'col-xs-12', 
                       'onchange' => "changeHidden(\"departFlightTimeMin\")"]
         ])->widget(\yii\jui\SliderInput::classname());
```

As you can see, I just put it in the HTML options array which is the third input to the $form->field function. Hope this helps!